# Did Emmanuel Macron call a teenager an "idiot?"

Tags: politics, quotes, france

[This article from *The Telegraph* (June 22, 2018)](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/06/22/teenager-emmanuel-macron-publicly-reprimanded-calling-manu-upset/) mentions that Emmanuel Macron called the teenager who was not respectful an "idiot"; emphasis is mine:

> President Emmanuel Macron is facing criticism for giving a public dressing down to a teenager who cheekily called him “Manu”after it emerged the boy is hiding at home to avoid mockery at school.
>
> Mr Macron reprimanded the boy on television this week after he shouted 'You all right, Manu?' as the 40-year-old mingled with the crowd at Mont Valérien fort near Paris.
>
> A clip of the incident, in which **Mr Macron called the boy an “idiot”** and said he should call him  “Monsieur” (Sir) or “Monsieur le Président” (Mr President), went viral online after the French leader posted it on his Twitter account.

I watched the clip, but it doesn't seem like he called the boy an *idiot*. Is there another clip? Why did they say Macron called the teenager an "idiot"?

Comment: Can you give a link to the video?  Preferably one that M. Macron can't delete.

Comment: In my experience, if a source is too lazy to indicate that what they denote with quotation marks is *not* a quote but rather their translation, you should be extremely skeptical about that translation.

Comment: This really looks much more like a question about the accuracy of a certain translation, which is not exactly something we're good at here.

Comment: @MadScientist I think we can be OK at it -- at translating maybe a sentence even if not a whole book. Post on Meta if you think this ought to be off-topic, but many of [my answers about quotes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2703+[quotes]) have included or required translations (e.g. the ones about Pascal, Horace, Sophocles, Van Gogh, Marie Antoinette, Augustine, and Pope Gregory IX).

Comment: @thunderblaster: Be aware that [some journalists](http://www.abc.net.au/mediawatch/transcripts/s3737515.htm) use single-quotations for paraphrase, and double-quotations for transcriptions.

Comment: @thunderblaster I think it would be most unusual to include the original (untranslated) text in an English-language popular newspaper, i.e. I think that all 'quotes' are always translations.

Comment: @ChrisW I agree that it would be unusual and it is apparently unusual for a news outlet to even point out that a conversation occurred in a language other than English and it was translated on the reader's behalf. I strongly disagree with that, but I am not the news' target demographic. Nonetheless, I find silent, opaque translations are frequently dubious.

Comment: @NateEldredge: how could Macron delete a video?

Comment: @Taladris: The article says that Macron tweeted the video.  The link in the tweet might go to a copy of the video that he controls (on his own site, uploaded from his YouTube account, etc) and could delete.  He might also delete the tweet itself.

Comment: Words like "idiot" and even "imbecile" are **remarkably different** in French.  It's not possible for the typical Brit or Yank to understand the use of these words.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

To summarise up front, he used the word *imbécile* which is more or less like "idiot", but he used it as an element of an idiomatic figurative phrase which means "you can play-act someone who doesn't care or doesn't know better" or "in a remarkably (and in this case inappropriately) juvenile way" -- not saying that "you 'are' an idiot", saying "you can 'play' an idiot".

In my opinion, this is different for three reasons:

- It's literally different -- using the verb *faire* (*Tu peux faire l'imbécile*) instead of *être* (*Tu peux être imbécile*)
- It means something different -- e.g. to 'be' an idiot is permanent and not a matter of choice, to 'play-act' was temporary (maybe even comic in the right circumstance)
- In any language I've been told that it's better if a teacher criticises behaviour than criticises the person -- better to say for example "that was naughty behaviour (which you needn't perpetuate)", rather than "you are a naughty boy". And it's better to make constructive criticism.

---

*[Faire l'imbécile](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/faire%20l'imb%C3%A9cile/fr-fr/)* is a specific phrase:

> s'amuser de façon espiègle, folâtrer

It's literally to "make (like) an idiot" or to act out -- he's not saying that the boy *is* an idiot -- he is accusing him of fooling around, perhaps of mockery.

Given the *Chant des Partisans* I take it that the occasion was a World War Two memorial, to honour and remember those who resisted and were killed -- and that M. Macron was there to represent the French State's honouring the fallen -- not a political occasion.

I understand (having attended similar ceremonies) why he might be prickly about it. I don't think he was especially prickly, more pedagogic. The boy's calling him "Manu" stuck out like sore thumb, and it's so informal that it's, in my opinion, obviously intended to be disrespectful, or at best inviting M. Macron to share the joke.<sup>**1**</sup>

[Here is a transcript](http://www.europe1.fr/politique/tu-mappelles-monsieur-le-president-emmanuel-macron-recadre-un-adolescent-3685961) of the French:

> "Tu es là dans une cérémonie officielle. Tu te comportes comme il faut", poursuit alors Emmanuel Macron. "Tu peux faire l'imbécile. Mais aujourd'hui c'est la 'Marseillaise', et le 'Chant des Partisans'. Tu m'appelles 'Monsieur le président de la République' ou 'Monsieur'".

My translation:

> You are (there) in an official ceremony. You behave yourself properly (literally, 'as it requires'). You can play the fool. But today, it's the *Marseillaise*, and the *Chant des Partisans*. You (must) call me "Mister the President of the Republic", or "Mister (i.e. Sir)".

It's also worth mentioning that, in my opinion, the French have an old-fashioned notion of politeness and formality, beyond what I think is normal in the UK or the USA (see e.g. the LA Times' article on when to use *Tu* as opposed to *Vous* for example), and which is taught in schools and by adults.

I'm not sure I'd call it "a public dressing down" even -- more like a correction. I get the impression from the video that M. Macron went on, went back, kept talking, in order to try to help, to find some good and agreeable advice to offer: "do things in the right order, first get your diploma."

---

Some people (in comments) are wondering why he talked so long.

It seemed to me that, having started their conversation on the wrong foot, "Manu" was trying to find something conciliatory, some common ground -- i.e talking about school, knowing this is exam-time, encouraging him to do well -- with body language like patting him on the arm, twice, as if trying for a *rapprochement* -- and asking him if agreed (*d'accord?*), and saying "I'm counting on you (to be exemplary in future)" -- he even said "je compte sur *vous*" (not "sur *toi*") by the time he got around to saying that, i.e. addressing him respectfully as an adult/citizen (or as representing a plural).

[The Tweet](https://twitter.com/EmmanuelMacron/status/1008770776391127042) says,

> Le respect, c’est le minimum dans la République – surtout un 18 juin, surtout en présence des compagnons de la Libération. Mais cela n’empêche pas d’avoir une conversation détendue – regardez jusqu’au bout.

My translation:

> Respect is the minimum in the Republic - especially on June 18, especially in the presence of the companions of the liberation. But that doesn't prevent having a relaxed (informal, friendly) conversation -- watch (this video) to the end.

Note the definition of [respect](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/respect/68670)

> - Sentiment de considération envers quelqu'un, et qui porte à le traiter avec des égards particuliers ; manifestations de ces égards : Manquer de respect à quelqu'un.
> - Sentiment de vénération envers ce qui est considéré comme sacré : Le respect des morts.
> - Considération que l'on a pour certaines choses : Le respect de la parole donnée.

My translation:

> - Feeling of consideration towards someone, which sustains treating them with particular regards ; or the manifestation of these regards : (example of the word used in a phrase) to lack respect toward someone
> - Feeling of veneration towards that which is considered sacred: (example of the word used in a phrase) respect for the dead
> - Consideration that one has for certain things: (example of the word used in a phrase) respect for the given word (e.g. for keeping a promise)

I think that M. Macron is (whether or not you agree) hereby implicitly disclaiming having been disrespectful himself.

Also there's a related phrase in French, *faire le singe* -- literally "make the monkey", figuratively "act like a monkey (or a clown)" or "to clown around" -- because it's a standard figurative phrase, you'd be missing some of the *nuance* if you only translated each word literally.

---

It might be worth mentioning the place, too, which according to the OP was [Mont Valérien](http://www.mont-valerien.fr/):

> Du lieu de l'Histoire au premier des Hauts lieux de la mémoire nationale :
>
> Lieu de culte médiéval devenu forteresse militaire au cours de XIXème siècle, le Mont-Valérien a été le principal lieu d’exécution de résistants et d’otages en France par l’armée allemande pendant la Seconde Guerre mondiale.
>
> La multiplicité des parcours des 1008 fusillés, nous permet aujourd’hui d’en décrire la diversité. Après la guerre, le site est choisi pour honorer la mémoire des morts pour la France de 1939 à 1945, et, le 18 juin 1960, le général de Gaulle y inaugure le Mémorial de la France combattante.
>
> Ces hommes, assassinés parce qu’ils étaient résistants, otages, Juifs ou communistes sont autant de rappels à notre histoire qui firent naturellement de ce site le premier des Hauts lieux de la mémoire nationale du ministère de la Défense, aujourd'hui géré par l'Office National des Anciens Combattants et Victimes de Guerre.

My translation:

> From a place in History to the first of the High (important, altar-like) places in the national memory:
>
> A medieval place of worship, become military fortress during the 19th century, the Mont Valérien was the principal place of execution of the members of the resistance and hostages in France by the German army during the second world war.
>
> The multiplicity of the itineraries of the 1008 people shot, allows us today to describe their diversity. After the war, the site is chosen to honour the memory of those who died for France from 1939 through 1945, and, on June 18 1960, General de Gaulle inaugurated there the Memorial of France at war.
>
> These men, assassinated because they were resistance, hostages, Jews, or communists, were as such (or were so many) reminders of our history who consequently made of this site the primary of the High places of the national memory of the ministry of Defence, today managed by the National Office of the Veterans and Victims of War.

---

Going back to the quoted definition, i.e.

> s'amuser de façon espiègle, folâtrer

If I paraphrase these definitions of [espiègle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/espi%C3%A8gle) and [folâtrer](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fol%C3%A2trer/34392), then (together with my own understanding of the phrase), the definition says, more or less, "to amuse oneself" ... comic; transgressive but not mean, almost innocent; doesn't know better; unworried -- the implication is that the boy ought to show more respect than to act that way here -- it may also imply that *we* are not amused.

That's close to how [Europe1's reporting](http://www.europe1.fr/politique/tu-mappelles-monsieur-le-president-emmanuel-macron-recadre-un-adolescent-3685961) after the fact characterizes the boy's greeting:

> Alors que le président de la République saluait plusieurs jeunes attroupés derrière des barrières, l'un d'entre eux, après avoir entonné les premiers mots de l'Internationale, **s'est amusé** à apostropher l'hôte de l'Élysée d'un "ça va Manu" ? Mais le jeune homme a été immédiatement repris par Emmanuel Macron. "Non, non", a-t-il rétorqué, alors que le jeune garçon, semblant vite regretter cette familiarité, s'excusait : 'désolé monsieur le président".

My translation:

> As the president of the Republic was greeting several youths who were trooped behind barriers, one of them, after sounding the first words of the *Internationale*, ***amused himself** by abbreviating<sup>**2**</sup> the host of the *Élysée* by a "*ça va Manu?*" But the young man was immediately taken up by Emmanuel Macron, "No, no", he replied, while the young boy, seeming to quickly regret this familiarity, was excusing himself: "sorry (or 'abject apologies') Mister President."

---

One more thing, he wasn't just criticising the boy's behaviour -- he was criticising his French, which I think of as normal and as natural as breathing, it's how people (children) learn French. There are [varieties or registers](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais) of French, and you're taught to use the right register on the right occasion.

Where I'm living it's normal to say "Bonjour Monsieur !", "Bonjour Madame !", "Bonjour !" to everyone you pass on the street. I once absent-mindedly said "Bonjour Monsieur" to an approaching child, and the enormity of what I'd said made him catch his breath and correct me: "*Je ne suis pas un 'Monsieur' ! Je suis en enfant !*"

---

<sup>**1**</sup> A comment below tells me that when the boy says, "*ça va Manu*?", that "Manu" is an abbreviation of "Emmanuel (Macron)". So it's a bit analogous to greeting the Queen of England or the Prince of Wales as, "Hey Lizzie!", or, "How's it going, Chuckles?"

<sup>**2**</sup> The French verb *apostropher* dosn't even have an equivalent in English that I can think of. Its [definition](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define%3Aapostropher) is, "*Adresser brusquement la parole à (qqn), sans politesse*", i.e. "address speech to someone brusquely, without politeness."

Comment: Indeed, French formality even extendes to their pronouns.  You can insult or disrespect someone by referring to them with the informal/familiar pronoun “tu” (meaning “you”), rather than the formal pronoun “vous” (meaning “you”, but denoting more respect.)

Comment: +1 for the translation. For the last paragraph, Macron said "Si tu veux faire la révolution, tu apprends d’abord à avoir un diplôme et à te nourrir toi-même", so "if you want to do the revolution, first learn to get a diploma and get a paying job". So I wouldn't call  his words "good and agreeable advice" ;-)

Comment: @JulienLopez Are you saying that isn't good advice, that you disagree with it?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Another thing is, it seems to me is that (knowing and) expecting and teaching proper behaviour, correcting school-children's misbehaviour, is accepted as a job of adults collectively -- teachers, parents, *whoever is in charge*, bystanders -- again, contrasted with UK and USA where the attitude might be more like "strangers shouldn't tell children what to do". And the kid clearly knew he was being transgressive -- when M. Macron replied "No, no no no" then the kid apologised. It was after that that "Monsieur le président" went on to tell him what he *should* have said, and why.

Comment: @ChrisW Certainly. I don't see why students shouldn't protest. And it is undoubtedly not agreeable, it is more of a scolding.

Comment: @JulienLopez According to the article cited in the OP, the fellow-students aren't protesting -- they're mocking the poor kid who misbehaved and was corrected.

Comment: @ChrisW I was referring to Macron's words: "revolution". Basically Macron is saying the student shouldn't say anything because he doesn't have a job.

Comment: This is the only answer that provides an *accurate* translation of the tone (and even gives a relevant explanation of the French formalism to contextualise the situation). All the other answers mistranslate, lose relevant nuance, or speculate.

Comment: Perhaps a more idiomatic English translation would be "You're making a foll out of yourself"

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar I agree that would be more idiomatic in English. I get the impression however that the French is criticising the behaviour and not the person -- i.e. criticising the foolery, not the "self", not the boy ... so I don't think he's calling the boy an idiot, even if he is characterising the behaviour as undignified or disrespectful.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar Here, it would be 'act' or 'play the fool' or 'fool around'. It's older and less common now, but it's the version equivalent to the French expression's focus on the behavior.

Comment: I would suggest that this answer note that "Manu" is a nickname for "Emmanuel." I'm not familiar with it, and from context I initially thought it was an honorific, just one less formal than "Monsieur." I didn't realize that it was a nickname until I googled it.

Comment: @JustinLardinois Thanks for the advice, I didn't know "Manu" either. I added a summary at the top, too, as the answer is getting long.

Comment: Your comment on referring to the royals by nickname is sound, and it would be equally odd to see someone refer to Theresa May as 'Tessa'. However, it is quite normal to refer to Jeremy Corbyn as 'Jezza', indicating that it's not just a matter of linguistic/cultural convention, but also about personality.

Comment: @AkselA I think it is a matter of linguistic/cultural convention, and not only a matter of personality but (according to Macron at least) especially a matter of time and place. Macron said, almost indulgently, "You can (or 'you may') kid around.", but he continued, "But not here, not today: you (must) behave (literally 'carry') yourself as it (i.e. the occasion) requires," I imagine the occasion will have been people standing at attention, a master of ceremonies, flags, anthems, bands, mourners, wreathes, welcomes, speeches, monuments, medals, and perhaps a message about preserving the memory.

Comment: Sure, but the way he responded, especially the length and lecturing nature of his response, I have to believe is due to Macron's personality. The kid's comment was short and innocent; is it imperceivable that another French politician would have just shrugged at it, or even welcomed it? Looking at the video, the mood right then and there wasn't exactly reverent, making the kid's comment less transgressive than what you make it out to be.

Comment: @AkselA IMO the kid's comment must have been intentionally rude (as discussed, only "playing" at being "innocent"). According to [the LA Times](https://frenchly.us/la-times-explains-mystery-vous-vs-tu/) he'd need to have been a veteran the French student May 1968 riots (IOW be about 70 years old) to have earned the right to even call Macron "*tu*", let alone "Manu". Yes Macron might in theory just accept the kid's apology and say nothing more, I don't know his personality: a politician given an audience, an opportunity and a duty to lecture on patriotism and French social values, I don't know.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: Note that this twist of language was possible in English as well, it just got lost -- "thou" / "ye" used to be the more informal form of address, with "you" being the more respectful form. At some point English merely dropped the informal form altogether.

Comment: The idiomatic expression in English is *play the fool*

Comment: @DevSolar I think (furthermore) that there's no "royal we" in French -- "we do it this way" becomes "*on fait comme ça*" ([etymologically](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/on), "man does it this way") ... whereas "one does it this way" sounds affected, "man does it this way" odd (asocial, anthropological, pseudo-scientific), and "'the' man does it this way" quite far out. Avoiding "*nous*" (e.g. "we do it this way ... unlike them, and unlike you lot") seems to me to avoid implying divided social classes and out-groups.

Comment: @reinierpost That ("play the fool") is how I chose to translate it, in the answer. Ily's comment called it "older and less common now" though (or perhaps it isn't idiomatic in American or in British English, I don't know which). "*Faire l'imbécile*" is quite informal, almost vulgar (or certainly familiar), and definitely a rebuke in this context -- it's less polite than "play the fool" IMO, it's something (simple language) you might say to reprove a younger child who's misbehaving ... but it has the same meaning as "play the fool", and isn't IMO disproportionate as a reply.

Comment: It's simply impossible for the typical yank or brit to understand French language usage.  A simple example is: a few brits and yanks would know that "you 'really should' say 'Bonjour' in France".  But the full, massive, weight of how much you need to say bonjour is totally misunderstood.  A "translation" of failing to, at the least mumble bonjour, would approach ....... spitting in someone's face.  The "clickbait" newspaper articles at hand are just absurdly whacky.

Comment: @Fattie I like [this anecdote](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/28981/5753) on that subject, because it's memorable, i.e. "1) *Bonjour* 2) *un café* 3) *s'il vous plaît*".

Comment: Fantastic, @ChrisW !   I'd say it wasn't to discourage rudeness, it was to discourage rost-bifs from dropping in  :)

Answer (score 38):

The French word Macron used to address the teenager was "imbecile", although in an advisory form: "You can act like an imbecile, but..."

Video here: [Emmanuel Macron tells teenager: 'Call me Mr. President'](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/06/19/europe/emmanuel-macron-president-video-intl/index.html)

The rest is a matter of translation, I suppose. CNN (in the above link) translated it as "fool", or more precisely "you can play the fool". I'm not a native French speaker, but in my experience the French use the "imbecile" word more easily than an English speaker would, so the connotation is less melodramatic.

Also "faire l’imbécile" [is synonymous](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_l%E2%80%99imb%C3%A9cile) with "faire le fou", so the "play the fool" translation seem the more idiomatic translation. "Fool around" would have been another [possible idiom](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/faire-le-fou) for the translation.

Comment: Here's another link with the video and a transcript (untranslated): http://www.europe1.fr/politique/tu-mappelles-monsieur-le-president-emmanuel-macron-recadre-un-adolescent-3685961

Comment: +1 Wow, thanks for the video. That seems like one hell of a long response to a mere *"ça va, Manu?"*... was that lecture something he was trying get that off his chest or something? (Mostly referring to the second half of what he said... it seems an awful lot to add to the first half unless the kid had previously said something to that effect... unless I missed something else he said here?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Macron was (also) pissed that the teen was humming the Socialist [Internationale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Internationale).

Comment: Ohhh huh, that would explain it, thanks! I didn't see this in the video.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think none of the videos posted captured that part. It's what the papers said though.

Answer (score 4):

No. The correct interpretation is `fool`, not `idiot`.

French is a very contextual language.

As has been already highlighted `Faire l'imbécile` is a specific turn of phrase.

The best definition comes from l'Académie française who state [in their dictionary](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/imb%C3%A9cile):

> ***Faire l'imbécile***, commettre des excentricités, des sottises, ou, en
>   particulier, faire celui qui ne comprend pas.

It is quite clear from the definition provided by l'Académie française that its not remotely possible to construe `Faire l'imbécile` as meaning `idiot`. It is clear from the above definition that the terminology relates to acknowledgement of a state of pretence rather than a direct accusation of inferiority.

Answer (score -8):

There was a time when psychologists categorized people with low IQs into several different categories.

Moron - IQ 51 to 70.

Imbecile - IQ 26 to 50.

Idiot - IQ 0 to 25.

As compared to an average human score of 100.

> The term imbecile was once used by psychiatrists to denote a category of people with moderate to severe intellectual disability, as well as a type of criminal.[1](http://fathersmanifesto.net/koko.htm) The word arises from the Latin word imbecillus, meaning weak, or weak-minded. It included people with an IQ of 26–50, between "idiot" (IQ of 0–25) and "moron" (IQ of 51–70)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imbecile[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imbecile)

In common language moron, idiot, and imbecile are used as synonyms, but if someone is an idiot by that old technical definition calling them an imbecile or a moron would be complimenting their intelligence.

I presume that a stupid person would have an IQ over 70 but significantly lower than the average of 100.

Thus I am amused when people accidentally compliment the intelligence of things like computer programs by calling them stupid.

Thus saying in French that someone behaves like an *imbecile* is not the same thing as saying in French that they are an *imbecile*, let alone saying in English they are an imbecile, let alone saying they are an idiot.

Note that the sign language using gorilla Koko (1971-2018) has been alleged to have an IQ of 90.

http://fathersmanifesto.net/koko.htm[1](http://fathersmanifesto.net/koko.htm)

Or to have an IQ between 75 and 95.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koko_(gorilla)[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koko_(gorilla))

Comment: -1 because this answer presume it's meant literally -- but *Faire l'imbécile* is a standard [figurative](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define%3Afigurative) phrase.

Comment: How does this answer the question? First, the French word *imbécile* has been in the language since the 15th c. and English borrowed the word from French soon after. So the fact that it gained a technical meaning in the psychological literature of the early 20th century is irrelevant. Second, as the other answers clearly state, Macron did not in fact call the kid an 'imbécile', he used an expression 'faire l'imbécile' which is not the same. Third, the fact that 'imbecile' has a particular meaning in English has no bearing on its meaning in French.

Comment: -1 for assuming that the modern meanings of words match their etymology. (That the etymology is wrong is another issue.)

Comment: @SáT: That language isn't acceptable here.

Comment: +1 for alot of effort, We all make mistakes, and you clearly tried to do research